# Button not responding to OnClick

Tags: android, button, onclick

I've set up a button in my XML layout, then set it up with an onClickListener in my Activity. Once I click the button, nothing happens. I have set up a TAG, so once the button has been pressed, it should show a message in the LOG.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I have found out what the problem is, whenever I remove the code

```
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
    ft.commit();

 }
```

everthing works perfectly. I'm not sure how I'm going to fix this, any help would be appreciated...

Activity

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String TAG = "TEST";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.image_grid_fragment);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Utils.enableStrictMode();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
        ft.commit();

    }

    Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d(TAG, "clicked");

        }
    });

  } 
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try another debug also in your `onCreate() (like Log.d(TAG, "log cat is showing data");)` to check whether log is being shown or not. if not then try by restarting eclipse. Also verify you are importing `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: May be its a logcat issue.Try showing in Toast Message

Comment: check your import statements to make sure that you have import `android.view.View.OnClickListener
` and not `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Comment: check import packegs use view.onclicklistner

Comment: I've done everything and nothing still shows up for some weird reason, maybe it's something to do with my other code?

Comment: @Jack Any updates on this? I've been having the same issue. A button works on some devices, not on others. When it doesn't work, I see a `Sending WAIT chunk` in the log.

Comment: I just added a line to print to the logcat at the beginning of the activity, and things seem to work. This is quite baffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are importing `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

*or you can also try like this:*

```
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG, "clicked");

    }
});
```

Comment: I've made sure I am importing "import android.view.View.OnClickListener;" and have used the code you provided me/added "View." in front of OnClickListener and it still does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG, "clicked");

    }
}),
```

**EDIT:**

The reason why it is still not working is because you have to import View.  If you are using  Eclipse press Ctrl+Shift+O to fix all imports.

Otherwise add

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you ain't catch the `clickEvent` on a `View`. Your `onClickListener` is not being called. Try to add `onClickListener` on your `View`. Just as the snippet shown below:-

```
Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d(TAG, "clicked");

   }
 });
```